# ASIHTTPRequest with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, authentication

I need to connect to a protected site and try to use ASIHTTPRequest

Here is my code:

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/page.aspx"];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUsername:username];
[request setPassword:password];
[request setDomain:domain];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    [webView loadHTMLString:[request responseString] baseURL:[request url]];
    }
```

When I use NSLog to see [request responseString], I get the correct HTML, but the result is a blank white webview.
From the outgoing request warnings that little snitch displays, I see the initial request and one going to an external resource.

My guess so far is that the inital request correctly uses the authentication from ASIHTTPRequest and fetches the page, but the uiwebview will try to load the included .js files and since uiwebview is not authenticating, it will not render the page at all ...

Anybody knows how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest)? My guess is you have resources in that page that are not downloaded, like `http://myurl/image.jpg`

Comment: +1, particularly the section of the docs with the header "Using ASIWebPageRequest to load data into a WebView / UIWebView". That's your answer right there.

Comment: Thx it worked, I was looking at the docs, but wasnt able to find that :-( but I still have 2 minor problems .. I copied the code like in the sample and added [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];[webView loadHTMLString:response baseURL:[theRequest url]]; First, it will not automatically scale, just when I double-tap, secondly a (the only other) link on that page is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure about the scale problem, about the second one, have you tried "A more complex example" section of that doc? I actually never used neither personally `UIWebView` nor `ASIWebPageRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

ASIHttpRequest runs asynchronously. You need to put your webview loading code into the ASIHTTPRequest callbacks.  (requestFinished).

Add a method to your class as follows:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        [webView loadHTMLString:[request responseString] baseURL:[request url]];
    }
}
```

There is also a requestFailed method that you can use to trap additional errors, you should implement this as well.  One or the other of these methods will be called once ASIHttpRequest completes.

Note you will probably also need to set the delegate on the request before making the asynch call. (so same place you set the auth stuff).

```
request.delegate = self;
```

Comment: @gazmozzii - He probably SHOULD make this asynchronous, but that's not what he's doing. His `[request startSynchronous]` fires off the request and blocks right there until it returns, and then goes on to the next line in his code.

Comment: oops - missed that - nice to see everyone's on the ball :-)